# Making UIMenuController enable to make Copy and Paste in TextField without making textfield editable isUserInteractionEnabled = false

Tags: swift, uimenucontroller

I have textfield that `textfield.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` but I would to have the copy and paste enable in textfield in order when user select on it, it can open the menu to make copy, is there a way to make it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldShowMenuForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if (action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:))) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        UIPasteboard.general.string = cell.textLabel?.text
    }
}
```